# actions-on-google-dialogflow-session-entities-plugin not working in dialogflow's inline editor

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I haven't been able to create a Session Entity in Inline Editor, using this plugin: actions-on-google-dialogflow-session-entities-plugin.

I declared the variable/package:

```
const { sessionEntitiesHelper } = require('actions-on-google-dialogflow-session-entities-plugin');
```

Updated my json package

```
"dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "dialogflow": "^4.0.3",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^1.6.1",
     "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "actions-on-google-dialogflow-session-entities-plugin": "^1.0.1"
```

But when I call the the function

```
let conv = agent.conv();
   
    conv.sessionEntities.add({
    name: 'processo',
    entities: [{
      value: 'descarte',
      }, {
      value: 'cobrança',
      }]
  });
  conv.sessionEntities.send();
```

> It says that: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessionEntities' of
> null

Can't figure out how to make that work. I found lots of examples (even here) but no one implemented in Inline Editor.

Just a reminder, as I'm using Inline Editor, I'm inside these functions context:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
```

So, examples like this one: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-session did not help.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping, I appreciate any clue...

Diego Mesquita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're *also* using the "dialogflow-fulfillment" library, and it doesn't know how to create a `conv` object that also has the `sessionEntities` object created when you call `agent.conv()`.

The easiest solution is to stop using the 'dialogflow-fulfillment" library and *just* use the "actions-on-google" library. You don't need to use "dialogflow-fulfillment" just because you're using the Inline Editor. The two are fairly similar, and if you're just developing for Actions on Google, there isn't much reason to use "dialogflow-fulfillment".

If you need to use "dialogflow-fulfillment" since you need to support other platforms besides Actions on Google, things may be trickier. I haven't tried this but code something like this might work

```
  const entity = {/* Put your entity definition here */};
  agent.client.addJson_({sessionEntityTypes: [entity]});
```

As an aside, keep in mind that the "dialogflow-fulfillment" package has been deprecated, apparently in favor of writing the JSON manually. The "actions-on-google" package has also been deprecated as it does not support Actions v3 and the Actions Builder/SDK (which do not use Dialogflow).

Comment: Glad this has helped! Which approach did you go with?

Comment: Basically the code you suggested, see below:

const entity = {
    
      "name":"projects/myproject/agent/sessions/mysessionID/entityTypes/processo",
      "entities":[
        {
          "value":"cobrança",
          },
        {
          "value":"descarte",
         }
      ],
      "entityOverrideMode":"ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT"
    };
 agent.client.addJson_({sessionEntityTypes: [entity]});

Comment: Ops, actually this one(the first one I sent was missing some parts of JSON response:

const entity = {
         "name":"projects/myprojectName/agent/sessions/mysessionID/entityTypes/processo",
      "entities":[
        {
          "value":"cobrança",
          "synonyms":[
            "cobrança",         
          ]
          },
        {
          "value":"descarte",
          "synonyms":[
            "descarte",
            ]
         }
      ],
      "entityOverrideMode":"ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT"
    };
 agent.client.addJson_({sessionEntityTypes: [entity]});